# Header location issues while porting Qt code from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ubuntu

I'm trying to port code written in Qt on Windows to Qt on Ubuntu. The problem I'm facing is that it gives me this error for my `ui_windowform.h` header:

```
error: QtWidgets/QApplication: No such file or directory
```

I searched on Google for solutions but didn't find anything relevant. I've also added `INCLUDEPATH += $QTDIR/include/qt4/QtGui`to .pro file.

Comment: What's an error about not being able to locate a header file have to do with itoa?

Comment: agreed... not a great title :(

Comment: sorry guys,actually I was going to ask that question but I solved that by myself(as itoa is not ASCII standard so it was not working with gcc) then faced this one and mistakenly asked this question under this title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly of agree with LukasT, but Qt 4 does still have QApplication, however it is located in a slightly different location :)  .... or maybe :(

You should find it here: .../qt4/QtGui/QApplication .... or somthing like that, I can't quite recall now...

But I would definatley try to keep your Qt version the same on each platform then you garantee that you will have no Qt lib issues... compiler on the other hand is not garanteed :o (but I would not worry too much about that)

Comment: @user2617519 yeah, much easier then mucking around with different versions!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the original Qt code uses Qt5, QtWidgets/QApplication rings the bell from me [1] and you are pointing to Qt4 in Ubuntu. You should try to install Qt5 in Ubuntu.

[1] http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtwidgets-index.html